# exec(): Unable to fork in phMagick in server - laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, image-resizing, phmagick

Why this error occurs in server in `phMagick`

```
exec(): Unable to fork [convert "/tmp/php8mWiyg" -scale "216x216" "/var/www/html/public/uploads/album_photos/18_1418286497.png" 2>&1]
```

in `libraries/phMagick/Core/Runner.php`

my code:

```
$phMagick = new PhMagick(Input::file('photo'));
$phMagick->setDestination($path)->resize(180,180);
```

I am struck with this and don't know what to do.. **Pls help**...